# Unity freeze on run, looped Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, freeze

I'm trying to generate a flat world out of cubes, I have several nested for loops to cycle through the coordinates and to place each block. The unity game engine freezes when I run the application. From what I can tell the loops are correct are should work and exit properly. I originally thought maybe I was trying to instantiate too many objects so I reduced the amount considerably, but I still get the same issue. I've been staring at this code for a while now and can't find an issue, so I was wondering if anyone knows what this issue is?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour {

public readonly int chunkWidth = 2;
public readonly int chunkHeight = 2;
public GameObject TestBlock;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    spawnChunk (0,0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void spawnChunk(int posX, int posZ){
    for(int x = 0; x <= chunkWidth; x++){
        for(int y =0; y <= chunkHeight; y++){
            for(int z = 0; x <= chunkWidth; z++){
                //create object
                Instantiate(TestBlock, new Vector3(x + posX, y, z + posZ), Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just throwing an exception? `TestBlock` will be null.

Comment: TestBlock is assigned in engine, you drag a script onto an object, in this case an empty object then in the inspector you drag an object onto the type gameObject(TestBlock) on this script.

Comment: But at what point is it assigned at execution time? Have you tried debugging through your code to check the value within `spawnChunk`? Can you step over the call to `Instantiate` in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your deepest for loop, `x` will always be less than `chunkWidth`, causing an infinite loop; `z` isn't being checked against anything.

Change:

```
for(int z = 0; x <= chunkWidth; z++){
```

to:

```
for(int z = 0; z <= chunkWidth; z++){
```

and Unity should no longer freeze.